# 4-bit output are always Z value and show no waveform after simulation in LED blink codes

Tags: verilog

I'm writing 4-bit LED blink code with Verilog in Vivado.  I think my code and testbench are right, but the value of `DATA[3:0]` (which are the led output) is always in Z value.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Also, after running the simulation, there is no output waveform on my screen.  Does anyone know why this happened?

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module fluled(
    input CLK,
    input SW,
    output [3:0] DATA
    );
    reg CLK1s=0;
    parameter max = 5000000;
    reg [1:0] state =2'b00 ;
    reg [30:0] n =31'b0000000000000000000000000000000;
    reg [3:0] data = 4'b0000;

    always @(posedge CLK ) begin
        if(n==max)
        begin
            if(!CLK1s)
                CLK1s<=1'b0; 
                n<=0;
        end    
        else 
        n<=n+1;    
    end

    always @(posedge CLK1s ) begin
        case (state)
            2'b00:begin
                state<=2'b01;
                if(SW) begin
                    data<=4'b100;
                end
                else begin
                    data<=4'b0100;
                end
            end 

            2'b01:begin
                state<=2'b10;
                if(SW)begin
                    data<=4'b0100;
                end
                else begin
                    data<=4'b1011;
                end
            end

            2'b10:begin
                state<=2'b11;
                if (SW) begin
                    data <=4'b0100;
                end
                else begin
                    data<=4'b1101;
                end
            end

            2'b11:begin
                state<=2'b00;
                if(SW)begin
                    data<=4'b0001;
                end
                else begin
                    data<=4'b1110;
                end
            end

            default: data<=4'b1101;
        endcase
        
    end
endmodule
```

Here is the testbench

```
module tb_fluled();
        reg SW;
        reg CLK;
        wire  [3:0] DATA;

        initial begin
          CLK=0;
          SW=0;
          #100;
        end
      
        always #20 CLK=~CLK;
        always #30 SW=~SW;

         fluled uut(
            .CLK(CLK),
            .SW(SW),
            .DATA(DATA)
        );
endmodule
```

Comment: Oh I see... The code should be    always @(posedge CLK ) begin
        if(n==max)
        begin
                CLK1s<=!CLK1s; 
                n<=0;
        end    
        else 
        n<=n+1;    
    end

Comment: Yes. Moreover it is a good practice to use a dedicated reset signal to initialize registers.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog is case-sensitive which means that `data` and `DATA` are 2 different signals.

`DATA` in the testbench is Z because `DATA` in `fluled` is Z.  This signal is undriven, and undriven nets default to Z.

If you intended for `data` and `DATA` to be the same signal, the quickest fix is to add this line inside  `fluled`:

```
assign DATA = data;
```

For example, it could go near the top:

```
module fluled(
    input CLK,
    input SW,
    output [3:0] DATA
    );
    reg CLK1s=0;
    parameter max = 5000000;
    reg [1:0] state =2'b00 ;
    reg [30:0] n =31'b0000000000000000000000000000000;
    reg [3:0] data = 4'b0000;

    assign DATA = data;
```

Now, `DATA` is no longer Z.

Answer (score 0):

your DATA output is not driven by any logic. You have several ways to fix it. One is to drive it with your `red data` as `assign DATA = data` (see toolic's answer)

The other way is to change declaration of your ports:

```
module fluled(
    input CLK,
    input SW,
    output [3:0] data = 0
    );
```

Of course, you need to change your port binding in the testbench: `.data(DATA)`. The trick here is that you declare it as a `reg` in the body as well. This can be done differently too:

```
output reg [3:0] data
```

This way you can remove your `reg [3:0] data` declaration.
And so on.

My 2c about your code issues.
You use initialization of registers at their declarations. This is a part of a testbench, but not a part of RTL. It might be synthesizable in some fpgas but in general it is considered non-synthesizable. So, I suggest that you also provide a 'reset' to your module an initialize the values using the reset signal, i.e.,

```
    always @(posedge CLK1s ) begin
       if (reset) begin
          state <= 0;
          n <= 0;
          data <= 0;
       else begin
          case (state)
           ...
```

BTW, there is no need to type '0' 31 times in the constants. `31'b0` is enough (or just '0');  Verilog automaticlly 0-extends (unsigned) or truncates values.